# LibGDX - only draggable movement

Tags: android, libgdx, game-physics

:D
I'm currently creating my first ever LibGDX game for Android.
And I've run into a issue regarding the movement of my little player(which is a bucket ;)).
I want to make the bucket(player) only draggable on the x-axis, and not clickable to change position.
The y-axis won't be an issue, because the bucket will only be able to change position on the x-axis.
So I basicly want to make the bucket only draggable.
Sorry for my writing, English isn't my native language.

Here's a code snippet from my code, where the movement operates:

```
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){
    Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
    touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);

    //Check the values
    float touchPosX = Gdx.input.getX();
    float touchPosY = Gdx.input.getY();
    String touchXString = Float.toString(touchPosX);
    String touchYString = Float.toString(touchPosY);
    Gdx.app.log("Movement - X", touchXString);
    //Gdx.app.log("Movement - Y", touchYString);
    Gdx.app.log("Movement - BucketX", bucketXString);
    //Gdx.app.log("Movement - BucketY", bucketYString)
    camera.unproject(touchPos);
    bucket.x = touchPos.x - 64 / 2;;}
```

The code is a bit messy...

Comment: `bucket.x = touchPos.x - 64 / 2;;` In case that 64 is the width of your bucket, it should work that way. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is that the bucket only moves when you are dragging it, and right now what it does is move to whatever "x" you clicked/taped, even if that "x" is far from the bucket, thus "teleporting" it.

To do this, first have a boolean lets say, "btouched".

```
boolean btouched = false;
```

Then you will have to use an Input Processor (instead of InputPolling). to check in the touchdown event if the click/tap was inside the bucket, then only if it was, it will move in the drag event:

```
MyInputProcessor inputProcessor;

public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor{

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
    camera.unproject(touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(pointer), Gdx.input.getY(pointer), 0));
    if(bucket.contains(touchPos)){
        btouched = true;
    }else{
        btouched = false;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer){
    camera.unproject(touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(pointer), Gdx.input.getY(pointer), 0));
    if(btouched){
        bucket.x = touchPos.x - 64 / 2;
    }
    return false;
}

    ...
}
```

Dont forget to set the input processor:

```
inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```